# What is KeyError in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, keyerror

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1000, 500

WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))



IMAGES = {}

def load_images():
        IMAGES[1] = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("background/ROAD_02 (1).png"), (49, 49))
        IMAGES[2] = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("background/ROAD_02 (1).png"), (49, 49)), 90)
        IMAGES[3] = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("background/ROAD_03 (1).png"), (49, 49))
        IMAGES[4] = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("background/ROAD_03 (1).png"), (49, 49)), 90)
        IMAGES[5] = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("background/ROAD_03 (1).png"), (49, 49)), 180)
        IMAGES[6] = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("background/ROAD_03 (1).png"), (49, 49)), 270)
        IMAGES[7] = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("background/castle.jpg"), (100, 100)), 0)
        IMAGES[8] = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("background/ROAD_01 (1).png"), (49, 49))

board = [
            ["8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8"],
            ["8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8"],
            ["8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8"],
            ["8", "8", "8", "8", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "6", "8", "3", "1", "1", "6", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8"],
            ["8", "8", "8", "8", "2", "8", "8", "8", "8", "2", "8", "2", "8", "8", "2", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8"],
            ["8", "8", "8", "8", "2", "8", "8", "8", "8", "2", "8", "2", "8", "8", "2", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8"],
            ["8", "8", "8", "8", "2", "8", "8", "8", "8", "2", "8", "2", "8", "8", "2", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8"],
            ["1", "1", "1", "1", "5", "8", "8", "8", "8", "4", "1", "5", "8", "8", "2", "1", "1", "1", "8", "8"],
            ["8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8"],
            ["8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8"],

]

def draw():
    for x in range(20):
        for y in range(10):
            number = board[x][y]
            WIN.blit(IMAGES[number], (x * 50, y * 50))

    pygame.display.update()





def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    load_images()
    while True:
        clock.tick(60)
        draw()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit()

main()
```

Hi, This is my code. I am trying to make a tower defence game and this is the map. I try to draw the images to the screen by using the board but it couldn't work. It say that I have some key error to fix but I don't know. Can anyone help me?

Error Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GAME_01\test.py", line 59, in 
`main()`
File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GAME_01\test.py", line 54, in main
`draw()`
File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\GAME_01\test.py", line 41, in draw
`WIN.blit(IMAGES[number], (x * 50, y * 50))`
KeyError: '8'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Please provide the error that is occurring

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Edit your question to include the full traceback you get.

Comment: Your `board` is list of lists of `str`, while the keys in `IMAGES` are `int`. `"8"` is not same as `8`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your board is a bunch of strings, but the keys of the dictionary are integers.
try this instead:

```py
board=[
[8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
[8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
[8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
[8, 8, 8, 8, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 8, 3, 1, 1, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
[8, 8, 8, 8, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 2, 8, 2, 8, 8, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
[8, 8, 8, 8, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 2, 8, 2, 8, 8, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
[8, 8, 8, 8, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 2, 8, 2, 8, 8, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 1, 5, 8, 8, 2, 1, 1, 1, 8, 8],
[8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
[8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

KeyError in this case would be the key used in `WIN.blit(IMAGES[number], (x * 50, y * 50))`

`number` is a str while the dictionary key `8` you made uses an int

A few ways around this would be

### Changing the keys for `IMAGES`

`IMAGES['1'] = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("background/ROAD_02 (1).png"), (49, 49))`

### Changing the `boards` list to use ints instead of strs

```
boards=[
[8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
[8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
[8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
[8, 8, 8, 8, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 8, 3, 1, 1, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
[8, 8, 8, 8, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 2, 8, 2, 8, 8, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
[8, 8, 8, 8, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 2, 8, 2, 8, 8, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
[8, 8, 8, 8, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 2, 8, 2, 8, 8, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 1, 5, 8, 8, 2, 1, 1, 1, 8, 8],
[8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
[8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]]
```

### Or simply converting them when needed

`IMAGES[int(number)]`

Though the last option would be a slower way to do it, i'd go either of the first two